# Retrieve values from a list of maps using streams

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I have a list of maps:
`List<Map<String, Object>>`

The maps consist of the keys `name` and `position`.

I need to retrieve all values of the key `position` from all maps of the list.

Currently I have this:

```
public List<String> getPositions() {
    List<String> positions = new ArrayList<>();
    list.forEach( map -> {
        for ( Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet() )
            if ( entry.getKey().toString().equals( "position" ) )
                positions.add( entry.getValue().toString() );
    } );
    return positions;
}
```

Is it possible to do this faster with Java `Stream`?

Comment: `list.stream().map(m -> m.get("position").toString()).collect(Collectors.toList())`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I understand your question, I suppose the `list` has the following structure:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> listOfMap = new ArrayList<>();
```

And any number these `Map`s in the `list` can possibly have a key `"position"` which you want to use to extract the value. Use:

```
List<String> positions = listOfMap.stream()                         // Stream
                                  .map(map -> map.get("position"))  // Get from map a value by key
                                  .collect(Collectors.toList());    // Collect to List
```

I would like to add up that Stream-API is definitely not a substitution of `for-loops` like you have provided in the snippet. As its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) states, it should be *non-infering* and *stateless*. So, replacing a `for-loop` adding an element elsewhere using Stream is not a good idea - you have to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a List of Strings.  if you take values directly it will give you Objects.
List positions = listOfMap.stream().map(map -> **String.valueOf**(map.get("position"))) .collect(Collectors.toList());